# Change AppBar title value on carousel change without setstate

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm developing a gallery app looking like whatsapps photo gallery. I want the appbar title change when my carousel slider changes. I tried it with setstate but because I show the carouselslider in a showdialog, it doesn't work and I think it can be cause performance issues. I use getx in the project and is there any way to do it without setstate?

Here is my AppBar widget

```
  showGeneralDialog(
                        context: context,
                        barrierDismissible: true,
                        barrierLabel: MaterialLocalizations.of(context)
                            .modalBarrierDismissLabel,
                        barrierColor: Colors.black45,
                        transitionDuration:
                            const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                        pageBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext,
                            Animation animation,
                            Animation secondaryAnimation) {
                          return Dismissible(
                            direction: DismissDirection.vertical,
                            key: const Key('key'),
                            onDismissed: (_) => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                            child: Scaffold(
                              appBar: AppBar(title: Text(photoSender)),
```

And body of the scaffold is a carouselsliderbuilder, so when the carousel changes, I want the photoSender variable to change.

Any ways to do this?

Comment: have you tried using `Obx` widget??, i think you can use `obs` for the string variable, end wrap the `Text()` widget using `Obx`

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare you `photoSender` variable as `Rx<String>`:

   ```
   final photoSender = Rx<String>("");
   ```
2. Wrap your `Text` widget with `Obx/GetX`:

   ```
   appBar: AppBar(title: Obx(()=>Text(photoSender.value))),
   ```

Whenever your `photoSender` variable`s value changes, it will automatically update the text in your app bar.

To update the value:

```
photoSender.value = "John";
```